# Export customer store credit and points from Volusion DB

Tags: sql, csv, export, volusion

I came across this necessity lately and there is no explicit query or documentation on how to do this directly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is this SQL query

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.EmailAddress, SUM(g.GiftAmountLeft) AS 'Store Credit', SUM(rph.points) AS 'Reward Points' 
FROM Customers AS c JOIN GiftCards AS g ON c.CustomerID = g.CustomerID 
JOIN Reward_Points_History AS rph ON c.CustomerID = rph.customerid 
GROUP BY c.CustomerID, c.EmailAddress ORDER BY c.CustomerID
```

This will export customer ID, e-mail, store credit and reward points.

Comment: How do you know the schema? BTW, I'd do LEFT JOINs - just in case a customer has no gift card, or reward points.

Comment: @jarlh the query is set by Volusion customer support team. Editing the query is obviously up to your needs.